# What is the correct approach to persist protobuf messages

Tags: database, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go

Let's say I have a simple bookstore CRUD api with gRPC. It consists of a `book` protobuf message

```
message Book {
  string id = 1;
  string title = 2;
  Author author = 3;
} 

message Author {
  string name = 1;
}
```

I want to persist the books in a database. The records should be searchable and hence I cannot store them as bytes.
As I see there are two ways to do it

1. Convert to JSON and store: This works well for document databases. But in my applications, I always work with drivers/ORMs which impose some language-specific restrictions (like for mongo `bson:"_id"` tag for primary key in golang, `@Document` annotation for spring-data-mongo). This requires modifying the message and custom conversion logic
2. Create a corresponding struct/class: I can create a wrapper struct/class for the message and then write a mapper to map messages to these structs. The good thing here is you can pull all of your custom logic add more fields in these struct/classes. But we have to maintain these mappers

```
type BookWrapper struct{
  ID string // remove this from book message and add here
  Book
  createdAt int64 //extra props 
}
```

Wanted to validate and check what is the correct/idiomatic way (personally inclined towards second) to achieve persistence.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways of solving this, so I don't think it has an answer, as such; you could normalize the entire data to  RDBMS table/s layout, for storage and search. You could make it the problem of an index service such as elastic/lucene. Or anything in between.

Comment: There are many ways but generally you'll want to create app-specific types and map these to|from Protobuf on-the-wire messages and map these to|from your favorite storage mechanism. This way, there's more to|from but you more loosely coupled.